# What are the chances of Georgia and Chechnya rebelling while Russia is occupied in Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, republic-of-georgia

If Georgia and Chechnya want to reclaim any of the territory they recently lost to Russian aggression, now seems like the best chance they will get in a while now that Russia is occupied in Ukraine. As Russian manpower and equipment are being lost daily.

Why has this not happened yet? What is the likelihood Georgian and Chechen forces will launch a counteroffensive and open a second and third front for Russia to defend while Russia is occupied in Ukraine?

Comment: Chechnya is part of Russia and many Chechns are fightin for Russia now.

Comment: @convert: I know that. But I don't see the relevance of that information to the question being asked.

Comment: "Chechnya want to reclaim any of the territory they recently lost to Russian aggression" this part make then no sence.

Comment: This looks like an attempt to predict the future, which is off-topic. It might be possible to rephrase this to be about present or past events.

Comment: Chechnya's land and borders haven't changed in the Chechen Wars. Its level of autonomy has.

Comment: "Why has this not happened yet?" Nobody knows. From experience we kind of ask somewhat different questions for more insightful answers. Like "Have there people there or politicians mentioned such plans? Would this be a realistic endeavor? Are such opportunity-seeking wars happening often?" kind of questions.

Comment: This should probably be taken with a gain of salt, but under Kadyrov Chechnya has already moved significantly towards political Islam. https://www.csmonitor.com/World/Europe/2017/0920/Kremlin-frets-as-Russia-s-once-restive-Islamist-region-takes-up-political-Islam So they mostly got what the want. Besides professing allegiance to Putin, Russian law applies much less there.

Comment: The governments of both countries as are more pro-russian now. This must change first, they are unlikely to launch swift organized attack even under good opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem likely.

Putin's failure in the blitzkrieg attempt in Ukraine has to do with Russia's [weak expeditionary force](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4wRdoWpw0w). The Soviet army was built primarily for defense. It relied and relies heavily on rail for its logistics, and on most infrastructure being in place and intact. The focus of its logistics corps was to transport materiel across home soil.

It has been considerably more successful since switching to a "capture and hold" strategy. Once their troops have secured an area and established a relationship with allied locals - this doesn't work if they are mostly hostile! - they can rebuild access infrastructure. This means roads and rail to provide a high flow of munitions, and full civilian infrastructure to provide fuel and food.

Essentially, the strategy is to turn captured land into home soil, where Russian forces work well. Where cities have been destroyed by shelling, they rebuild. This has worked in Grozny, then in Abkhazia, and it [has already started in Ukraine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeqBVYNgOgA).

Fighting Russia on its home soil would mean fighting its complete industrial capacity, rather than the small fraction it can project abroad over road. Additionally, a defensive war would have near-unilateral domestic support in Russia and give Putin a justification for partial mobilization.

Comment: **Soviet army was built primarily for defense** this is a strong statement which is supported with nothing. Same about this one **considerably more successful since switching to a "capture and hold" strategy**, as the way I see it they are successful when using 50x more power than defenders and attacking against more outdated weapons than they have. It is easy to hold something when you have so much more manpower/tech. The sentence about rebuilding is laughable: rebuilding one house in a fully destroyed half mln population city is not a rebuilding.

Comment: @SalvadorDali there are obvious geographic factors here: Russia (and in the past the USSR) has a huge land border, which it must defend. The border stretches from the far east (bordering North Korea, China, Mongolia) through the central Asia, Europe and towards the Nordic countries. For the same reasons Russian main strategic interests require projecting force along its border. This is different from the US, which does not have much dangers along its borders, and whose "interests" require projecting force far away from the mainland.

Comment: @SalvadorDali The statement is supported by the linked video, which explains this. It might not be a strong proof, but I figure there's a lot more chance of a reader watching a youtube video than locating and reading a book on military strategy.